# Customize Navigation (Next/Prev) buttons on Compound Key Management screens

Tags: acumatica

The Item Warehouse Details are composed of a compound key of Inventory ID + Site ID. The navigation buttons on the Manage > Item Warehouse Details screen move between the latter part of the key, the Warehouse.

Would it be possible to customize them to navigate between Inventory IDs instead? What events / methods would allow for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to customize navigation buttons in Acumatica, you should redeclare some or all navigation buttons in an appropriate BLC extension. Below is an example showing how to implement navigation on the Item Warehouse Details screen only by Inventory ID:

```
using PX.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
    public class INItemSiteMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<INItemSiteMaint>
    {
        public PXFirstCst<INItemSite> First;
        public PXPreviousCst<INItemSite> Previous;
        public PXNextCst<INItemSite> Next;
        public PXLastCst<INItemSite> Last;

        public class PXFirstCst<TNode> : PXFirst<TNode>
            where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
        {
            public PXFirstCst(PXGraph graph, string name)
                : base(graph, name)
            {
            }
            public PXFirstCst(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler)
                : base(graph, handler)
            {
            }
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.First, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
            [PXFirstButton]
            protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                var graph = _Graph as INItemSiteMaint;
                if (graph == null) return base.Handler(adapter);

                InjectCustomWhereClause(ref adapter, graph, typeof(Where<True, Equal<True>>));
                return base.Handler(adapter);
            }
        }

        public class PXPreviousCst<TNode> : PXPrevious<TNode>
            where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
        {
            public PXPreviousCst(PXGraph graph, string name)
            : base(graph, name)
            {
            }
            public PXPreviousCst(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler)
                : base(graph, handler)
            {
            }

            [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.Previous, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
            [PXPreviousButton]
            protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                var graph = _Graph as INItemSiteMaint;
                if (graph == null) return base.Handler(adapter);

                InjectCustomWhereClause(ref adapter, graph,
                    typeof(Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Less<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>));
                return base.Handler(adapter);
            }

            protected override void Insert(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                adapter.Searches = null;
                base.Insert(adapter);
            }
        }

        public class PXNextCst<TNode> : PXNext<TNode>
            where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
        {
            public PXNextCst(PXGraph graph, string name)
                : base(graph, name)
            {
            }
            public PXNextCst(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler)
                : base(graph, handler)
            {
            }

            [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.Next, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
            [PXNextButton]
            protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                var graph = _Graph as INItemSiteMaint;
                if (graph == null) return base.Handler(adapter);

                InjectCustomWhereClause(ref adapter, graph,
                    typeof(Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Greater<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>));
                return base.Handler(adapter);
            }

            protected override void Insert(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                adapter.Searches = null;
                base.Insert(adapter);
            }
        }

        public class PXLastCst<TNode> : PXLast<TNode>
            where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
        {
            public PXLastCst(PXGraph graph, string name)
                : base(graph, name)
            {
            }
            public PXLastCst(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler)
                : base(graph, handler)
            {
            }
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.Last, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
            [PXLastButton]
            protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
            {
                var graph = _Graph as INItemSiteMaint;
                if (graph == null) return base.Handler(adapter);

                InjectCustomWhereClause(ref adapter, graph, typeof(Where<True, Equal<True>>));
                return base.Handler(adapter);
            }
        }

        private static void InjectCustomWhereClause(ref PXAdapter adapter, INItemSiteMaint graph,
            Type conditionToInjectCommand)
        {
            var bqlCommand = adapter.View.BqlSelect;
            var newCommand = new List<Type>(BqlCommand.Decompose(bqlCommand.GetType()));
            var newCommandCopy = new List<Type>(newCommand);

            var conditionToReplaceCommand = typeof(Where<INItemSite.inventoryID, Equal<Optional<INItemSite.inventoryID>>>);
            var conditionToReplace = new List<Type>(BqlCommand.Decompose(conditionToReplaceCommand).Skip(1));
            var conditionToInject = new List<Type>(BqlCommand.Decompose(conditionToInjectCommand).Skip(1));

            bool whereClause = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < newCommand.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                whereClause = whereClause || typeof(IBqlWhere).IsAssignableFrom(newCommand[i]);
                if (!whereClause) continue;

                if (newCommand[i] == conditionToReplace.First())
                {
                    bool found = true;
                    for (int index = 0; index < conditionToReplace.Count; index++)
                    {
                        if (newCommand[i + index] != conditionToReplace[index])
                        {
                            found = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (found)
                    {
                        newCommandCopy.RemoveRange(i, conditionToReplace.Count);
                        newCommandCopy.InsertRange(i, conditionToInject);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            var cmd = BqlCommand.CreateInstance(BqlCommand.Compose(newCommandCopy.ToArray()));
            var newAdapter = new PXAdapter(new PXView(graph, false, cmd));
            PXAdapter.Copy(adapter, newAdapter);

            var inventoryState = graph.itemsiterecord.Cache.
                GetValueExt<INItemSite.inventoryID>(graph.itemsiterecord.Current) as PXSegmentedState;
            if (inventoryState != null && inventoryState.Value != null)
                newAdapter.Parameters = new object[] { inventoryState.Value };
            else
                newAdapter.Parameters = new object[] { string.Empty };

            newAdapter.SortColumns = null;
            newAdapter.Descendings = null;

            adapter = newAdapter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. That is well above and beyond standard customization stuff. It will take some time to get my head around everything going on with this, but it does appear to generally work as needed.